# avoid browser prefetch files of lazy loaded modules in vuejs app

Tags: javascript, browser, vuejs2, vue-cli

i have a VueJS app and i'm using lazy loading modules, like this:

```
const Home = () => import("./Home.vue");
```

in order to reduce or minimize the resources impact during the initial page load.

The issue is that the browser still **prefetches all the resources at page load time**. See this:

[image]

Is there a way to avoid that and make the client download the resources only when (and if) needed?